# Крокозябры в  INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql

Использую такой запрос:

INSERT INTO gaz_k2_items(title,alias,catid,published,introtext,extra_fields,created_by,checked_out,modified_by,trash,access,ordering,featured,featured_ordering,hits,params,metadesc,metadata,language,yandex) VALUES('$title','$alias','$catid','$published','$introtext','$extra_fields','$created_by','$checked_out','$modified_by','$trash','$access','$ordering','$featured','$featured_ordering','$hits','$params','$metadesc','$metadata','$language','$yandex')

В СУБД значит такая ерунда:
?????? ?????? ????? ???? ?????????? ????????: ?? ???????? ??? ??????????? ? ???? ????. ?????? ??????? ??????????? ???????? ??? ?????? ?? ??????????? ?????? ?????? ?????? ? ?????? ?? ?????. ??? ?????? ??????? ??????????? ??????? ??? ???? ??? ????????? ??, ??????? ??, ? ???????? «???????????».<br> ???????? ??????? ????? ??????? ???? ?? ????. ?????? ??????????? ? ????, ? ?? ???????, ??? ?????? ????? ??? ??? ???????????? ????????? ??????. ?????? ????? ???????????? ??? ???? ? ???????????? ???????, ?? ??????????? ? ???????????? ???, «??????» ? ?? ???????????????????? ???????????? ???????????

Подскажите, что там можно с кодировкой натворить.

Comment: А какая кодировка на сайте и у БД? Можете попробовать принудительно установить кодировку перед отправкой данных с помощью запроса:

     SET CHARSET ваша_кодировка

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сразу после подключению к Базе Данных добавить следующий код:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query("set collation_connection='utf8'");
```

Также измените кодировку в самой Базе Данных на utf-8 или на ту что вам нужно, но кодировка в запросах что я написал выше и в вашей Базе Данных должна быть одинаковой.